# Retrofit2 - getting 400 bad request on POST with body

Tags: java, json, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit2.
Send a POST request with body (as a JSON array), but getting the "**400 Bad Request**".
Meanwhile sending the request from ***SoapUI*** and my http client (based on ***HttpURLConnection***) works fine.

API Interface for the service:

```
public interface ApiService {

    @POST( "let/fmir" )
    @Headers( {
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
            "Content-Type: Application/Json;charset=UTF-8",
            "Accept: Application/Json",
            "User-Agent: Retrofit 2.3.0"
    } )
    Call<LetPOJO> fmir(
            @Header( "Authorization" ) String authorization,
            @Body String body
    );
}
```

API service provider:

```
public class ApiServiceProvider {

    public ApiService createApiService() {
        // Prepare the Retrofit logger
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor( interceptor).build();

        // Build the Retrofit
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl( "http://1.1.1.1:3040/api/v1.0/" )
                .client( client )
                .addConverterFactory( JacksonConverterFactory.create() );
                .build();
        return retrofit.create( ApiService.class );
    }
}
```

Invoke service by declared API (input data were obfuscated):

```
ApiService apiService = ApiServiceProvider.createApiService();
Call<LetPOJO> call = apiService.fmir(
    "Basic NDUhg4234OQ==",
    "[\"L___1\",\"L___2\",\"L___3\",\"L___4\"]"
);
```

Log of Retrofit interceptor:

```
янв 24, 2018 10:12:38 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: --> POST http://1.1.1.1:3040/api/v1.0/let/fmir
янв 24, 2018 10:12:38 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Content-Type: Application/Json;charset=UTF-8
янв 24, 2018 10:12:38 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Content-Length: 139
янв 24, 2018 10:12:38 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
янв 24, 2018 10:12:38 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Accept: Application/Json
янв 24, 2018 10:12:38 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: User-Agent: Retrofit 2.3.0
янв 24, 2018 10:12:38 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Authorization: Basic NDUhg4234OQ==
янв 24, 2018 10:12:38 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: 
янв 24, 2018 10:12:38 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: "[\"L___1\",\"L___2\",\"L___3\",\"L___4\"]"
янв 24, 2018 10:12:38 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: --> END POST (139-byte body)
янв 24, 2018 10:12:39 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: <-- 400 Bad Request http://1.1.1.1:3040/api/v1.0/let/fmir (121ms)
янв 24, 2018 10:12:39 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Vary: Accept-Encoding
янв 24, 2018 10:12:39 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Content-Encoding: gzip
янв 24, 2018 10:12:39 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Content-Type: text/plain
янв 24, 2018 10:12:39 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Date: Wed, 24 Jan 2018 07:12:39 GMT
янв 24, 2018 10:12:39 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Connection: close
янв 24, 2018 10:12:39 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: Content-Length: 192
янв 24, 2018 10:12:39 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log INFO: <-- END HTTP (encoded body omitted)
```

Response's *Content-Type* is ***text/plain***, but expected **Application/Json**

For example, working SoapUI's request/response:
The request:

```
POST http://1.1.1.1:3040/api/v1.0/let/fmir HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Authorization: Basic NDUhg4234OQ==
Content-Length: 129
Host: 1.1.1.1:3040
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

And its response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 24 Jan 2018 08:33:12 GMT
Content-Length: 689

[{"id":"L___1"}]
```

The body is obfuscated also. 
As we can see *Content-Type: **application/json***

When I sending via **HttpURLConnection** - HTTP headers of the request are the same also and works fine:

- Authorization
- Content-Type
- Accept

However, GET request with Queries works fine via Retrofit.

I not found any solutions for this problem. In some cases propose to use `@Header` annotation as a method argument - but behaviour is the same.

This is the server endpoint:

```
@ApiOperation("Some description") 
@POST @Path("fmir") 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
@ApiResponses(value = { 
  @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "ОК"), 
  @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "some message"), 
  @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "some message") 
}) 
public List<Letter> getLet(
    @ApiParam(value = "Authorization header") 
    @HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) final String authorization, 
    @Context ContainerRequestContext context, 
    final List<String> letterIds) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that "Application/Json" is ok in @Headers? I would use "application/json" as content type as it is usually spelled (and also in RFC)

Comment: I believe Retrofit already sets the content-type header. Could you try again without the entire `@Headers( { ... } )` above that method? Also, could you post the server code of the `api/v1.0/let/fmir` end point? (or at least its method signature)

Comment: @DanielVoina, yes, I tried use in lowercase also, and debug Retrofit execution - it ignores case.

Comment: @BartKiers, 1. "Could you try again without the entire `@Headers( { ... } )` above that method?" - I tried - unfortunately the same. 2. I'll try to find the code - it will takes some time.

Comment: @BartKiers here is method signature: `@ApiOperation("Some description")
@POST
@Path("fmir")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiResponses(value = {
 @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "ОК"),
 @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "some message"),
 @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "some message")
})
public List<Letter> getLet(
 @ApiParam(value = "Authorization header") @HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) final String authorization,
 @Context ContainerRequestContext context,
 final List<String> letterIds
) {}
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the server endpoint expects a list of strings, I think your client will need to send this as well (an not send a string):

So, try this:

```
public interface ApiService {

    @POST( "let/fmir" )
    @Headers( {
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
            "Content-Type: Application/Json;charset=UTF-8",
            "Accept: Application/Json",
            "User-Agent: Retrofit 2.3.0"
    } )
    Call<LetPOJO> fmir(
            @Header( "Authorization" ) String authorization,
            @Body List<String> body
    );
}

...

ApiService apiService = ApiServiceProvider.createApiService();
Call<LetPOJO> call = apiService.fmir(
    "Basic NDUhg4234OQ==",
    Arrays.asList("L___1", "L___2", "L___3", "L___4")
);
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your participation and advice. I tried, and it helped - and now got 200 OK. It seems that it works now - I've got a JSON in the Response. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you take a look on my question, too? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67480896/6444297