# Sending list of objects in form-urlencoded request using Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2, x-www-form-urlencoded

This is my postman request:

[image]

I'm going to send a POST request using Retrofit2, Gson and RxJava2. This is my request:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Student") // I'm sure the address and name are correct
Completable Student(@Field("firstName") String firstName,
                    @Field("lastName") String lastName,
                    @Field("exam[]") List<Exam> exams
);
```

And this is Exam model created using POJO Generator:

```
public class Exam {

@SerializedName("score")
private int score;

@SerializedName("field")
private String field;

public void setScore(int score){
    this.score = score;
}

public int getScore(){
    return score;
}

public void setField(String field){
    this.field = field;
}

public String getField(){
    return field;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "Exam{" + 
        "score = '" + score + '\'' + 
        ",field = '" + field + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
}
```

Postman sends the request correctly and receives the response code 204 but my Retrofit request cannot send request correctly. How can I send list of objects in x-www-form-urlencoded request using Retrofit version 2 and RxJava version 2?

Comment: Use a `FieldMap` instead and fill the map before hand with dynamic keys .

Comment: can you share your error logs of retrofit because your are doing right so I want to understand what is the problem then?

Comment: @ADM: I replaced `@FieldMap(encoded = true) Map<String, String> Exams` and I got Response 204 but the value didn't set in server. I mean when I send GET request of Students to get its data, I received just firstName and lastName and Exam data is empty. but postman works correctly. Can you give me the example code, please?

Comment: Debug your request make sure the values are being sent as it suppose to be . https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded-using-fieldmap.

Comment: @NitinPrakash Its not the Retrofit error. I get my server error like this: `The request is invalid.`

Comment: change `@Field("exam[]")` -> `@Field("exam")` I'm presuming that you're using gson parsing

Comment: @DarshanMiskin Yes I'm using gson. I've already tried with and without `[]`, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali Try sending a raw json of your request in postman. I think the issue is with how the server is expecting the request body.

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali looks like you are trying to send a json like this `{
 "firstname": "",
 "lastname": "",
 "exam": [{
  "field": "",
  "score": ""
 }]
}` but the server is expecting a json like this `{
 "firstname": "",
 "lastname": "",
 "exam[0].field": "",
 "exam[0].score": "",
 "exam[1].field": "",
 "exam[1].score": ""
}`

Comment: @DarshanMiskin raw json doesn't get response.

Comment: Retrofit 2 has a json converter. i found it easier to use than RXJava 
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:'$version
Take a look at that

Comment: @Bristol I'm using converter-gson. Can you tell me how to send my request in your opinion?

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali one of the two raw jsons that I provided earlier should provide the response. click on the raw radio button in postman and send it.

Comment: @DarshanMiskin I got status 204 and correct Response using json `{"firstName":"Alireza","lastName":"Noorali","Exam":[{"field":"Math","score":90},{"field":"Physics","score":80}]}`

Comment: i used this tutorial before. it gives all what you might need https://abhiandroid.com/programming/retrofit

Comment: @DarshanMiskin Did you have any idea about trying with raw json?

Comment: did you try with @Body List<Exam> exams instead of @Field("exam[]") List<Exam> exams?

Comment: @tremendous7 `@Body` annotation is not allowed in `@FormUrlEncoded` requests. it produces this error: `@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.`

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali as of https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-10.2.5 response 204 is a valid response.   `@Field("exam[]") List<Exam> exams`  should work, if it provides you with a 204 response then your code is fine. The server just didn't send you any data.

Comment: @DarshanMiskin That's right, I know this, and I'm waiting for the status 204, but I'm not receiving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try with this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Student") // I'm sure the address and name are correct
Completable Student(@Field("firstName") String firstName,
                    @Field("lastName") String lastName,
                    @FieldMap Map<String, String>
);

  *****************************
// how to use the map
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("exam[0][field]","Math");
params.put("exam[0][score]","90");
params.put("exam[1][field]", "Physics");
params.put("exam[1][score]", "99");
```

Comment: and how to fill map? I know how to fill a Map but in this case I think it is a little different. can you fill the map in your answer?

Comment: is your JSON look like this?


{
    "exam": [
        {
            "field": "Math",
            "score": "90"
        },
        {
            "field": "Math",
            "score": "90"
        },
        {
            "field": "Math",
            "score": "90"
        },
        {
            "field": "Math",
            "score": "90"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 2):

If the Postman request works then this would be the Retrofit equivalent:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Student")
Completable Student(@Field("firstName") String firstName,
                    @Field("lastName") String lastName,
                    @FieldMap Map<String, String> fieldMap
);
```

and then run a loop to fill in the details

```
public void sendRequest(List<Exam> exams) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < exams.size(); i++) {
        map.put("exam[" + i + "].field", exams.get(i).getField());
        map.put("exam[" + i + "].score", String.valueOf(exams.get(i).getScore()));
    }
    yourApiService.Student(firstName, lastName, map); // enqueue or execute whatever
}
```

This is more of a simpler approach you could also look into custom a `JsonSerializer` with Gson.

Comment: Your answer is similar to Nitin Prakash's one